# use mysql on the command prompt

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, zend-framework

I typed

```
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

and I got

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

'/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I looked for the way to fix this error in books and internet search and I found several answers, all different and nothing works. Please don't post an answer if you are not positive that it will work

Answer (score 0):

First run ,

```
mysqld --print-defaults
```

find in output --socket=[path_to_socket] (it is path to socket file, which mysqld will create when run).
Then you should check is mysql is runing, you can check it with

```
ps axu | grep mysqld
```

if it is runing, then you can run

```
mysql -S [path_to_socket]
```

If it is will not help, please attach output of

```
mysqld --print-defaults
```